# MySQL - Search for string contains "_" with LIKE

Tags: mysql, wildcard

I have a MySQL table and I need to retrieve some fields from it. 
I need the string that contains `H_` and `HP_` Separately using two different query.

But the problem is the underscore is in the wildcard and i am unable to find correct result.

**Example Query of *HP_***

```
SELECT nc.`logname`, nc.`client_id`, nc.`Customer_Name`, cb.`bwm_day_cir_upload`, cb.`bwm_day_cir_download` 
FROM `new_client` nc
LEFT JOIN `client_bandwidth` cb ON cb.`client_id` = `nc`.`client_id`
WHERE nc.`logname` LIKE '%HP_%' AND nc.`Active` = 'y' ORDER BY TRIM(UPPER(nc.`logname`))
```

Comment: Escape it `\_` .

Comment: And when you run into problems like this, it is always worth to first check the documentation. [MySQL documentation for `like`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like): _"To test for literal instances of a wildcard character, precede it by the escape character. If you do not specify the `ESCAPE` character, `\\` is assumed."_

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As You told it's a wildcard. Then just escape it with `'\_'`

```
SELECT nc.`logname`, nc.`client_id`, nc.`Customer_Name`, cb.`bwm_day_cir_upload`, cb.`bwm_day_cir_download` 
FROM `new_client` nc
LEFT JOIN `client_bandwidth` cb ON cb.`client_id` = `nc`.`client_id`
WHERE nc.`logname` LIKE '%HP\_%' AND nc.`Active` = 'y' ORDER BY TRIM(UPPER(nc.`logname`))
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation to the rescue! Did you read the following page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Here's an excerpt:

> To test for literal instances of a wildcard character, precede it by
>   the escape character. If you do not specify the `ESCAPE` character, `\` is
>   assumed.
>
> - `\%` matches one % character.
> - `\_` matches one _ character.

Comment: I did't check it from here but do it from another place. Thanks to share.